# Close down voting for a bad question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, closed-questions

Let's say I asked a bad question and the question have been closed, but the voting is still open. Now someone answered my question resulting that I am unable to delete it. So every now and then someone see my question and vote it down because it is bad. So yes, I learned my lesson and desperately want to get that out of my life because I get -rep the whole time.

Is there a feature to close voting or when a question is voted closed to also close voting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the question is closed, it can't receive new answers, so closed questions without answers can be deleted.  But you should be careful with deleting too many questions, because it can give you a post ban.

And yes, a closed question can still receive votes (up and down). And if it has answers you can not delete it. But you can do several other things:

- edit the question to make it better.
- ignore the downvotes.
- flag a moderator for deletion (no success guaranteed).

The best solution is to learn from it, and next time you ask a question, try to make it a good one.  Read several other questions, and ask yourself, why is this a good (or bas question) and learn.

Comment: What is CW? and if it is alredy awnsered and then closed...

Comment: @lontgomjr, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts.

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention and asking for a deletion is also fairly pointless; the one time I did it, I was told "This is not fair to people who have earned reputation from your question; if you want, we can disassociate the question from your profile"

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers It depends a lot on context.  It may or may not be appropriate.  It's not *always* appropriate, but it sometimes is.  Part of it depends on the quality of the question, the quality of existing answers, whether or not it's possible to improve the question etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awnser